# How to open a webpage in Chrome incognito mode from an Android app

Tags: android, google-chrome, incognito-mode

Title says it all - I press a button from my app and it opens up a hard coded URL in the Chrome Browser on my phone. But I would like for it to open in incognito mode. If this can't be done with Chrome, the standard browser incognito mode would be fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Same thing here for Android